# Can you use UIAppearance to set the titleview of UINavigationItem?

Tags: ios, uinavigationitem, uiappearance, titleview

I currently use this code to set the titleView of my navigation item:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{ ...
   UIImage *navbarTitle = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navbartitleview1"];
   UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:navbarTitle];
   self.navigationItem.titleView =imageView;
}
```

Is there a way I could put this code using UIAppearance?

```
[UINavigationItem appearance]
```

is not valid.

Comment: Simply, No. If you're looking into the Header files, properties must be marked with UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR. UINavigationItem does also not comply to the UIAppearance protocol.

Comment: ah,that's what I figured, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No you wan't be able to do that with `UIAppearence`, what you can is to have a `UIViewController` from where all the others UIViewController will inherit. Think way you avoid having to put that code in all your `UIViewControllers`.