# iPhone - set app wide nav bar back button without text

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uiappearance

I've set an image to be the background image for all nav bar back buttons in my app using the appearance property. I do it with the following code in the applicationDidLoad method.

```
UIImage *backButton = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-nav-back"];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:backButton forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

My problem is that whenever the back button appears the image is stretched due to the name of the previous view being set as the back button's title. Is there a system wide way I can stop the title being set? Also attempting to set the back button's title to blank in the actual view controllers has no effect :(

```
[self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem setTitle:@""];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UIBarButtonItem *customItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:plainButton] autorelease];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customItem; 
[(UIButton*)self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.customView addTarget:self.navigationController action:@selector(popViewControllerAnimated:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Make a custom barButtonItem and exchange it for the default back button.

Comment: Thanks BabyPanda but I wished to be able to set it system wide and not just per view.

Comment: by "system wide", if you mean set it for all the viewControllers, then you could make a category like `UIViewController+CustomNavigation` and implement the category method  `- (void)setLeftBarButtonItem:(UIButton*)plainButton;` in the viewControllers

Comment: Hey BabyPanda, thats indeed what I was doing but I just wondered if there was a way to do it using the appearance property for the nav bar. I don't really like having to import and call the category for each class, was hoping there might be a "cleaner" way to do it

Comment: well, shame that i haven't found a way to barely implement navigationbar appearance to do the work yet...

Answer (score 9):

I found a way to achieve what you want.

First make your back image resizable, so that it wont be stretched to the length of the back button:

```
UIImage* backImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"back"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 20, 0, 0)];
```

Set this image as backButtonBackgroundImage via UIAppearance:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:backImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Last, move the title out of the visible area:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(-1000, -1000) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Only downside is, that the width of the backButton isn't changed, so that your `UINavigationBar` title can be off center.

Answer (score 1):

Found this question that tells me unfortunately I cannot do what I wish :(

[Can you use UIAppearance to set the titleview of UINavigationItem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11230952/can-you-use-uiappearance-to-set-the-titleview-of-uinavigationitem?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

You simply can do this without using a back bar button image as well if you need the same appearance as default `BackBarButton` image. Just write the following lines before you navigate to other controller:

```
  UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
      initWithTitle:@"Back"
              style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
             target:nil
             action:nil] autorelease];
  [[viewcontroller navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem:backButton];
```

This will solve your problem. Also, you will be able to change the image as per your need using another method of `barButton`. 
Please let me know if you find any problem or you were looking for another problem.

Comment: Thanks Turan but I wished to be able to set it system wide and not just per view.

Answer (score 1):

The way i got around it was:

```
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.clearColor()], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

This works on iOS 8.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old post, but if I had come across the post, there must be others too looking for it.

Just adding to Stephen's answer: This makes text white for Normal and Selected state. This makes it system wide with just 2 lines. However, the image takes up the space for white text and looks quite bad.

For system wide back button, you use the code from above

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.clearColor()], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.clearColor()], forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)
```

Comment: This works but the only problem is that it impacts **all** `UIBarButtonItems`, not just the back button.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3.x**

Add this line in AppDelegate file
`UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffsetMake(0, -60), for:UIBarMetrics.default)`